# In wordpress 4 need pagination plugin working with any tables

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I need pagination for created my new tables in wp 4.2.
I tried to use some common plugins like
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-paginate/installation/

But I found that it(and some other plugins I watched) works only with post table. Could you to point to me to some good pagination  plugin working with any tables ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let me to ask in other way : I need pluging not to connecting with any table, just to draw pagination pages by given parameters like n=base url, number of pages etc... Splitting of data I can make on myself. I made something like this in codeogniter 2 projects. If there is something good for this ?